# Elasticsearch multi query two value for each column filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some query like this

```
GET _search
{
"size":6,
"query":{
    "filtered":{
        "query":{
            "query_string":{
                "query":"some keyword",
                "fields":["title","content"]}       
            },
    "filter":{
        "match":{
            "channel.SiteName":"Photo Video"}}        
        }    
    },
"sort":[
    {"_score":{"order":"asc"},
    "date":{"order":"desc"}}
    ],
"aggs":{"SiteNames":{"terms":{"field":"channel.SiteName"}}}
}
```

and it works,

But I just get abstract value from my query

I want to get 3 values from for each SiteName = Photo and Video